# I have issue with constraint layout like i am using two layouts and it is showing perfect but at the runtime only second layout is shown

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Here is the result I would like to get:

[image: what i want]

I think the given images shown my complete problem but take a look at the code of my nested layout. Here is the result I currently get:

[image: what i am getting]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".Main2Activity">

<!--MY FIRST LAYOUT -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/song_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/song_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/song_thumbnail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.079" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/song_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.081"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/recyclermore" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/song_artist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/more_buttons"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/song_thumbnail"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/song_name"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.413" />


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/more_buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/song_thumbnail"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.003">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.075"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/recycleraddto" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.101"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/add_to"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/recyclerdelete" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/set_ringtone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.201"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/delete"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/recyclerringtone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rename_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.452"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/set_ringtone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/recyclerrename" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am not providing the full code because i try but this site not allow me to do this and show me error (It looks like your post is mostly code please add some more details ) it is like a headache to new users to post a questions o this site.

Comment: can you show us what it looks like?

Comment: yes of course still i am trying to add images and complete code

Comment: you can use relative layout inside ConstrainLayout..

Comment: Okay is it solve my problem?

Comment: @MansiJha ConstraintLayout is an extremely powerful layout and while using it you rarely need to use nested views. So the first thing I would do is try to get rid of the nested ConstraintLayout.

Secondly, if you could attach images of what you are trying to build and what you are actually seeing it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @MansiJha set solid values to avatar.

Comment: @Rishabh i use this nested layout because i want to hide and show the second layout at runtime

Comment: @MansiJha You could use a Group for hiding and showing multiple views at runtime. Creating a nested ViewGroup is not necessary.

Comment: sorry Rishabh but as i told you i am new to android so i am unable to get your point please can you give me some example for that or try my code and answer it with edit please if you can